# set certain form inputs to certain values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

How do i cycle through all form inputs with a certain name and set those to a specified value?

I tried this jsfiddle and i can't get it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/qvcA6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link-1").click(function() {

$('[name=price]','#myform').val('0.00');
      });  
});
```

EDIT: i didn't think it would matter, but the array key for the form field name isn't accounted for. So all of your examples are working but they break when i put keys in the field names. Anybody know how to go about accounting for the keys? updated jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/qvcA6/8/

Comment: Side question for my own edification: isn't this going to cause problems when submitting the form? Typically names in a form are unique, and are used to create the request parameters.

Comment: Greg, price is an array in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the jfiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/qvcA6/1/
There were two issues.

1) The attribute value needs to be surrounded by quotes.

2) The name of your inputs were 'price[]' and not 'price' so the jquery selector didn't match anything

Comment: that worked for that instance. I thought it would work when the price inputs have a key. But it doesn't. Would it be super complicated to account for all price inputs regardless of their key? http://jsfiddle.net/qvcA6/8/

Comment: no that wouldn't be too hard. You can use this: `$('[name^="price"]','#myform')` the `^=` is the 'starts with' selector so it will get all elements having a name that starts with the word price. That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvcA6/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link-1").click(function(e) {
        $('#myform').find('input[name="price[]"]').val('0.00');
        e.preventDefault(); // use prevent default instead of inline js on the link. 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks for the e.preventDefault(); trick. Didn't know that one! upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

The name of your inputs is `price[]` not `price`, also it would be more efficient expecially in a long form to specify the tag name when using the attribute equals selector.

```
$('#myform input[name="price[]"]').val('0.00');
```

Here is a link your modified fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qvcA6/7/

Answer (score 0):

See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/qvcA6/17/):

```
$(function() {
    $("#link-1").click(function() {
        $("input[name^=price\\[]", "#myform").val('0.00');
        return false;
    });
});
```